# What dose the word "shots" means in the Zero-Shot Learning in machine learning?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

the Zero-**Shot** Learning means learning without any example .

and one-**Shot** Learning means learning with one example....

so now I guess the word **shot** might comes from snapshot but not pretty sure.

Comment: Are *any* of these words *right* here? The only phrase here that makes sense to me is the "this can reduce ... factor of four" phrase. Please edit to give more background context so we can try to make a guess at the meaning. In the meantime, I'm voting to close as unclear. Please note also, "proofreading" requests are off-topic here. That means that we can't just quote a passage and say "is there anything wrong at all in all of this"; we must ask about a specific concern we have with some part of it, and make our concern clear.

Comment: I don't think this is a question about English - it seems to be about *terminology*. A quick Google shows that 'zero-shot learning' is a machine-learning (AI) problem setup. You should really look into the etymology of the terminology if you want to know why it is called what it is

Comment: If you type the phrase "zero-shot learning" into your favourite search engine it will take you to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-shot_learning) which explains the origin of the term. (I've no idea why you'd think the word is wrong, but you don't explain that.)

Comment: The OED has a definition for *shot* that seems to fit the sense here:  "colloquial (originally US). A single occasion of doing or obtaining something; a turn, a ‘go’; usually in (so many) dollars (cents) a shot."  It's pretty much understood by all native English speakers today. Thanks America!

Comment: @BillyKerr I suggest promoting that to an answer. I presume it came from hunting contexts, in which "a shot" can be "a unique and brief opportunity to shoot." See also Eminem, who "only gets one," and Hamilton, who is not throwing his away.

Comment: @AndyBonner - yeah, but I can't be 100% sure though, it's merely what I suspect.